# Trouble with installing npm and supervisor package on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, installation, amazon-web-services, node.js

I'm running an Amazon Linux AMI and successfully installed node.js by `wget`'ing the source, untarring the file, and running `./configure` and then `sudo make install`. When I installed npm:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

It outputs:

```
npm cannot be installed without nodejs.
Install node first, and then try again.

Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH?
Note that running as sudo can change envs.

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

But node is clearly installed (running `node -v` shows its version), so it must be that node is not in my path.

I open `~/.bash_profile` and add this line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then run `source ~/.bash_profile`

and try to install npm again, only to find that it outputs the same message as last time, which the exact same PATH.

Then, the weird thing is that I notice that npm is actually installed! Running `npm -v` shows its version. Hm....

Then I run `npm install supervisor` in the directory of my app, and the supervisor folder is there in `/node_modules`, however the `supervisor` command does not exist.

Installing supervisor outputs:

`npm WARN prefer global supervisor@0.3.1 should be installed with -g`

so I try `npm install -g supervisor` which outputs

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/supervisor'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

so I try `sudo npm install -g supervisor`

but the output is `sudo: npm: command not found`

So to sum up, npm seems to be working fine, although the output when installing it would lead one to believe otherwise, and the supervisor package seems like it's installed, but its command is not working.

Any help on figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd highly recommend installing node and npm using yum (as per [the docs](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager)): `sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/amzn1/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm` and 
`sudo yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm`. In addition to keeping things up to date, it tends to avoid a lot of the problems encountered when compiling from source.

Comment: @cyberx86 just uninstalled node and reinstalled with yum. Node works, but npm doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: If it was installed, it should be in /usr/bin/npm which is a symlink to /usr/lib/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js. Can you confirm that npm is in fact installed? (I use Amazon Linux and node.js/npm so I can confirm that it should work.)

Comment: @cyberx86 `/usr/bin/npm` does exist, and so does `/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. Running `npm -v` returns `-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

Comment: @cyberx86 and adding `/usr/bin` to my path gets npm working! :)

Comment: It is looking in the wrong location (`/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`) - possibly as a side effect of the modifications to PATH made previously. Try `which npm` which should return `/usr/bin/npm` - you might still have an old copy of npm installed.

Comment: @cyberx86 yup, it was my PATH, however I cannot seem to get supervisor working after `npm install`ing...

Comment: I see you beat me to it - just as a point of mention, as root, `echo $PATH` should return something similar to: `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin`. You might need to clear your npm cache after all the changes. Try `npm cache clear` before installing any packages.

Comment: @cyberx86 just installed supervisor as root user, and it's working! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem - I'll post the recommendations as an answer, and hopefully people with the same problem will have an easier time of it in future.

Comment: @cyberx86 yup, and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When possible, it is best to avoid compiling packages. In addition to often installing in non-standard locations, software that is compiled from source is much harder to keep up to date. Node.js provides a procedure to install from a repository - which includes npm and some other related components. The repository is kept up to date and is rarely more than a couple of days behind the source code. Moreover, [instructions are available](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) for Amazon Linux specifically:

```
sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/amzn1/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm.
```

`npm` should install to `/usr/bin/npm` which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js.` Of course, with some of the modifications made to your PATH, it is possible that npm may not be found. `echo $PATH` (as root) should resemble:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin
```

One of the common problems when previous installs with npm fail is a corrupted cache - clear your npm cache (`npm cache clear`) and see if you have any success. Of course, installing a package globally, needs to be done as root.

Comment: As at Aug/13 the packages on nodejs-tchol.org appear to be unmaintained.  They're 2 months and a major version number out of date.